Clickhouse server unreachable when using the INET IP to connect
I am able to install clickhouse-server (version 24.11.1.2557) on my Ubuntu machine (version 22.04.5). I confirm that the service started successfully by:
a. Checking the log
2024.12.03 21:26:40.561958 [ 19146 ] {} <Information> Application: Listening for http://[::1]:8123
2024.12.03 21:26:40.561999 [ 19146 ] {} <Information> Application: Listening for native protocol (tcp): [::1]:9000
2024.12.03 21:26:40.562021 [ 19146 ] {} <Information> Application: Listening for MySQL compatibility protocol: [::1]:9004
2024.12.03 21:26:40.562043 [ 19146 ] {} <Information> Application: Listening for http://127.0.0.1:8123
2024.12.03 21:26:40.562069 [ 19146 ] {} <Information> Application: Listening for native protocol (tcp): 127.0.0.1:9000
2024.12.03 21:26:40.562100 [ 19146 ] {} <Information> Application: Listening for MySQL compatibility protocol: 127.0.0.1:9004
2024.12.03 21:26:40.562104 [ 19146 ] {} <Information> Application: Ready for connections.

b. Tried to connect using clickhouse-client:
# clickhouse-client --host ::1 --port 9000 --user default --password
# clickhouse-client --host localhost --port 9000 --user default --password
# clickhouse-client --host 127.0.0.1 --port 9000 --user default --password

c. And then perform a query:
:) show databases;

Query id: 63fb83b3-90f5-4142-bed4-b9b818c1b481

   ┌─name───────────────┐
1. │ INFORMATION_SCHEMA │
2. │ default            │
3. │ information_schema │
4. │ system             │
   └────────────────────┘

4 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.003 sec. 

My problem is when accessing it from the outside. My machines IP in the local network is:
# ifconfig

enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.132.211.8  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.132.211.255
        inet6 fe80::3a1f:b72b:7770:3272  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 58:11:22:b4:1d:d9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 269386  bytes 363492229 (363.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 70159  bytes 12476734 (12.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8237  bytes 3995072 (3.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8237  bytes 3995072 (3.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

And when I attempt to connect the client using the command below, it returns an exception.
# clickhouse-client --host 10.132.211.8 --port 9000 --user default --password
ClickHouse client version 24.11.1.2557 (official build).
Password for user (default): 
Connecting to 10.132.211.8:9000 as user default.
Code: 210. DB::NetException: Connection refused (10.132.211.8:9000). (NETWORK_ERROR)

This is both encountered using a remote machine and the same machine where the server is running.
I already checked both users.xml for this line:
<clickhouse>
    ...
    <users>
        <default>
            ...
                <networks>
                    <ip>::/0</ip>
                </networks>
            ...
        </default>
    </users>
    ...
</clickhouse>

And config.xml for these lines:
<clickhouse>
    ...
    <listen_host>::</listen_host>
    <listen_host>::1</listen_host>
    <listen_host>127.0.0.1</listen_host>
    <listen_host>10.132.211.8</listen_host>
    ...
</clickhouse>

And also confirmed that the file /etc/clickhouse-server/user.d/allow_only_from_localhost.xml is removed (it actually is missing after the installation)`.
I also allowed tcp connections to port 9000 using ufw allow 9000/tcp in case this a firewall issue. What else could I be missing?

I assumed you've confirmed the server is reachable? can you use ss and confirm the interface and port clickhouse is listening on? e.g. ss -tuln Do you support ip6? i would limit your config to <listen_host>::1</listen_host> and try again
